# How to populate the csv file?

Tags: android, csv, sqlite

i'm creating a csv file with the data from the database. All the data of the selected consumer Id's must  append into the csv file. In my program the csv file was attached on email, let's say I have 3 selected consumer ID, the email sent, but when I checked the csv file, the first selected ID was did not show up and it leaves the first row blank, while the 2nd and 3rd append on the csv. I don't what happen why I cannot see the data of the first ID i selected. help me please..
here's my code:

```
 private String getConsumersDetails(ArrayList<String> arraylistConsumerId)
{           
    for (int j = 0; j < arraylistConsumerId.size(); j++)
    {
            //Cursor cursorConsumerDetails = null;
            Cursor cursorConsumerDetails = databaseAdapter.getCursorRegisteredConsumer(Integer.parseInt(arraylistConsumerId.get(j)));
            //if (cursorConsumerDetails.getCount() == 0)
                //cursorConsumerDetails = databaseAdapter.getCursorRegisteredConsumer(arraylistConsumerId.get(j));
                // consumerData.append("\n"+lastname+","+firstname+","+middleinitial+","+cellphone+","+emailadd+","+carefriend+","+company+","+regdate);     

            if (cursorConsumerDetails.getCount() > 0)
            {
                lastname = cursorConsumerDetails.getString(cursorConsumerDetails.getColumnIndex(Constants.CONSUMER_LASTNAME));
                firstname = cursorConsumerDetails.getString(cursorConsumerDetails.getColumnIndex(Constants.CONSUMER_FIRSTNAME));
                middleinitial = cursorConsumerDetails.getString(cursorConsumerDetails.getColumnIndex(Constants.CONSUMER_MIDDLEINITIAL));
                cellphone = cursorConsumerDetails.getString(cursorConsumerDetails.getColumnIndex(Constants.CONSUMER_CELLPHONENO));
                emailadd = cursorConsumerDetails.getString(cursorConsumerDetails.getColumnIndex(Constants.CONSUMER_EMAIL));
                carefriend = cursorConsumerDetails.getString(cursorConsumerDetails.getColumnIndex(Constants.CONSUMER_CAREFRIEND));
                company = cursorConsumerDetails.getString(cursorConsumerDetails.getColumnIndex(Constants.CONSUMER_COMPANY));
                regdate = cursorConsumerDetails.getString(cursorConsumerDetails.getColumnIndex(Constants.CONSUMER_REGISTRATIONDATE));

                code = cursorConsumerDetails.getString(cursorConsumerDetails.getColumnIndex(Constants.CONSUMER_COMPANYCODE));


            }

            consumerData.append("\n"+lastname+","+firstname+","+middleinitial+","+cellphone+","+emailadd+","+carefriend+","+company+","+regdate);    


       }

    return consumerData.toString();
}
```

This one calls the code above..
    ....

```
consumerData = new StringBuilder();
                    File personFile;
                    time = String.valueOf(calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY))+String.valueOf(calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE))+String.valueOf(calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND));
                    personFile = createCSV("Person_Table_"+date+"_"+time, Constants.COLUMN_STRING_PERSON_TABLE, getConsumersDetails(arraylistConsumerId), fileCounter, false);

                    createEmailWithAttachments(personFile);

....
```

Comment: i don't know how its done in android but in general to obtain a csv file from sqlite database.
1> .mode csv
2> .output filename.csv
3> select * from table;

Answer (score 0):

```
I don't know how its done in android but in general to
 obtain a csv file from sqlite3 database.
```

```
.mode csv
.output filename.csv
select * from table;
```

csv file will be present directory where the sqlite database file is stored.